# Ajax response blcoked in IE by jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to call API through $.ajax() function.

I'got response in firefox but it got blocked in IE by jquery 
debugger shows error msg :

> permission denied  jquery-1.4.2.min.js line 127 character 287

Comment: Do you request a file on a different server (or another protocol)

Comment: Post the code you are using to make the request.

Comment: yes i request on API which on different server $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
        url: testUrl,
        success: function(msg){
     
       if(msg!="" && msg!=null){
      jAlert(msg);
     }
          },
      error:function(){
       jAlert("error");
      }
     });

Comment: i got response for the same code in FF but IE showing error that permission denied what's the reason and how to resove it???

Comment: testURL is:: http://alertbox.in/pushsms.php?username=prontoinfotech&api_password=45c48oax9yb52c0s9&sender=1&to="+mobile+"&message=www.icicibank.com&priority=1

Answer (score 0):

You don't really get an error in IE but if you debug it then you'll see that the server is never hit and or code never reaches the success block.

For AJAX requests, www. is seen as a sub-domain and breaks the same-origin policy for the xmlhttprequestobject.

Make sure the domain in your AJAX request matches the domain of the page and your javascript file, that is, you should get rid of the www. in your $.get() function

Or if you still need to do the $.get to different domain, try using XHR options in your jQuery (> 1.5.1) ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
   url: a_cross_domain_url,
   type: "GET",
   xhrFields: {
      withCredentials: true
   }
});
```

Hepe it'll help

Comment: XHR to a different domain is not allowed?

Comment: Not by default. There's an article explaining why http://fettig.net/weblog/2005/11/28/how-to-make-xmlhttprequest-connections-to-another-server-in-your-domain/